# What is "his" in "his was a rags-to-riches tale"?

Tags: possessive-pronouns

Is "his" in "his was a rags-to-riches tale" used instead of "his tale" to avoid repeating words? Or is it something else?

Comment: It is "his tale", for example "his tale was of rags-to-riches."

Comment: As in **His was delapidated cottage; His was a three-legged dog; His was a shrewish wife.**

Comment: Rags-to-riches is an idiom. The word is used as an adjective in this sentence. It is an idiomatic expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is a replacement for "his tale". You see this pattern often enough:

> My laptop was powerful, but his was weak

> His was a weak laptop